# fopen in laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel

I've trying to open a url using fopen in a laravel controller. I have the following code:

```
            $sendlink = "http://login.bulksms.my/websmsapi/ISendSMS.aspx?username=username&password=password&message=testing&mobile=601212345678&sender=Demo&type=1"; 

        $fp = fopen($sendlink, 'r');
         $result = ''; 
            $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
            //update to send history
            $pieces = explode(":", $result);
            $eng_status = $pieces[0]; // piece1
            $eng_sms_id = $pieces[1]; // piece2

            //record msg
            $newGroup = new Message;

            $newGroup->company_id = $companyId;
            $newGroup->contact_id = $sendId;
            $newGroup->contact_number = $phone;
            $newGroup->msg = $eng_msg;
            $newGroup->code = $eng_sms_id;
            $newGroup->save();      

        // close the socket connection:
        //deduct credit
        if($eng_status == '1701') {
            //minus credit
            $balanceCredit = $balanceCredit - $engCredit;
            $group = Company::where('id', $companyId)->first();

            $group->sms_credit = $balanceCredit;
            $group->save();     

        }
        fclose($fp);
```

but the funny thing is it just does not work and all it gives in return is

```
//www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

any idea what could go wrong? I have this same php code working on a non framework file. so it doesn't seem to be a server issue. Hope can get some help here.

thanks

Comment: Which variable contains this value ? I tested the fopen part inside a laravel project and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a mistake on my end.

it required to do a urlencode before sending the message for processing.

Tq